# Why knockout binding does not overwrite viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, knockout.js

I am using knockout foreach binding to bind a div. But when i click the button a new model does not get created and model keep expanding continously.I want my data should be binded only once not again and again.What wrong i am doing. Here is [Here is a demo of problem](http://jsfiddle.net/wLzgm750/1/)

```
function bindValues() {

            var obj1 = { Name: ko.observable("location & size") };
            var obj2 = { Name: ko.observable("font") };
            var obj3 = { Name: ko.observable("border lines + fills") };
            var obj4 = { Name: ko.observable("alignment + padding") };

            var model = new Object({
                Styles: ko.observableArray()

            });

            model.Styles.push(obj1);
            model.Styles.push(obj2);
            model.Styles.push(obj3);
            model.Styles.push(obj4);

            ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("style-accordion"));

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because you push the value again and again to your observableArray
and you call applyBindings everytime, you only need to apply the bindings once and overwrite the array

```
        var model = new Object({
            Styles: ko.observableArray()

        });
        ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("style-accordion"));


    function bindValues() {

        var obj1 = { Name: ko.observable("location & size") };
        var obj2 = { Name: ko.observable("font") };
        var obj3 = { Name: ko.observable("border lines + fills") };
        var obj4 = { Name: ko.observable("alignment + padding") };

        // override instead of push
        model.Styles([obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4]);


    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLzgm750/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're calling `ko.applyBindings` every time bindValues is called. This function should only be called once in your case.

I'd recommend moving `bindValues` inside your ViewModel like this:

```
var model = {
    Styles: ko.observableArray(),
    bindValues: function() {

        var obj1 = { Name: ko.observable("location & size") };
        var obj2 = { Name: ko.observable("font") };
        var obj3 = { Name: ko.observable("border lines + fills") };
        var obj4 = { Name: ko.observable("alignment + padding") };


        model.Styles.push(obj1);
        model.Styles.push(obj2);
        model.Styles.push(obj3);
        model.Styles.push(obj4);
    }

};
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/tjjc5bcq/